# Dangers associated with sous-vide temperature and time

Tags: food-safety, pork, sous-vide

What's the risk associated with leaving pork (vacuum sealed) in water at 35 °C (95 °F) for 12 hours? It's probably a common mistake with sous vide cooking, forgetting to turn the bath on.

Answer (score 6):

Toss it. That's right in the middle of the danger zone, and hasn't been at a high enough temperature to impede bacterial growth. Not worth the risk.

Answer (score 2):

The conditions you've described are ideal for growing a pretty vibrant culture of *clostridium botulinum* (botulism). Maybe you could distill some Botox serum out of it (please note that this is a flippant comment - don't try to make homegrown Botox), but please do not consider serving it as food to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Would you eat meat that has been sitting on your porch for a night?

To get a clear understanding of underlying problems, read this: http://www.douglasbaldwin.com/sous-vide.html